# Reading recommendations for target tracking?

Tags: references, deep-learning

I'm a software engineer working on Deep Learning, but mostly for NLP. I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and some cameras and wanted to play around a bit with target tracking (implementing models from scratch in TensorFlow, not using OpenCV or similar), i.e. actually understand the techniques. What are currently the most important papers in this area? I was unable to find any good reading list for this topic and there are enough papers that starting out it's hard to know which techniques to focus on.

Comment: SISR (sequential importance sampling resampling) technique may be a good starting point. You can check this one: "A Tutorial on Particle Filters for Online Nonlinear/Non-Gaussian Bayesian Tracking". (2002 paper, quite old now).

Answer (score 0):

Start with the best.

The [results](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2017/results) of the ILSVRC 2017 competition were released yesterday (July 17, 2017).  The winner in the two tracking categories, Task 3c (Object detection/tracking from video with provided training data) and Task 3d (Object detection/tracking from video with additional training data), was this team:

Jiankang Deng(1), Yuxiang Zhou(1), Baosheng Yu(2), Zhe Chen(2), Stefanos Zafeiriou(1), Dacheng Tao(2), (1)Imperial College London, (2)University of Sydney

Here are their publications, source code, and a presentation:

[1] [Deep Feature Flow for Video Recognition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07715) 
Xizhou Zhu, Yuwen Xiong, Jifeng Dai, Lu Yuan, and Yichen Wei, IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR), 2017.

[2] [Flow-Guided Feature Aggregation for Video Object Detection](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10025.pdf), Xizhou Zhu, Yujie Wang, Jifeng Dai, Lu Yuan, and Yichen Wei. Arxiv tech report, 2017.

Presentation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0rMHE6ehGw

Source Code
https://github.com/msracver/Deep-Feature-Flow

The code has the following prerequisites:

- Python 3.2.0+
- Microsoft's MXNet
- Cython
- OpenCV (Python bindings)

Their code requires a GPU with at least 6GB of memory.

Another option is [ROLO](http://guanghan.info/projects/ROLO/).  The author is Guanghan Ning and he uses You Only Look Once (YOLO) for detection and uses TensorFlow to implement LSTMs for tracking.

His published a paper:
[Spatially Supervised Recurrent Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Object Tracking](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.05781), IEEE International Symposium on Circuits and Systems, 2017

His code is here: https://github.com/Guanghan/ROLO

Project page: http://guanghan.info/projects/ROLO/

Prerequisites:

- Python 2.7 or 3.3+
- TensorFlow
- Scipy
- OpenCV (Python bindings)

Some videos of his work:

- [ROLO example on unseen sequence: Surfer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qElDUVmYSpY)
- [ROLO example on unseen sequence: Boy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dDsvVEt4ak)
- [ROLO example on unseen sequence: Jumping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7Bxf4guddg)